# insert,update and delete using a tree view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I would like to know how to insert,update and deleting using a tree view from database and i want to have one table but be able to have parents and nodes on the tree view retrieving from database.

if you have any links that might help me give me guys 
Thanks .

Comment: @user1514138 plz read it http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I think you can avoid dovnvotes and possibility of closing this question by providing what you have done so far and the specific area that you are struggling with :)

Answer (score 1):

Trees are hierarchical; relational databases are set-based.

You have to write the mapper from the tables to the tree view or use an existing one.